# How to get specific part of url?

Tags: php

I am working on search function which I want make my search more easier and I had store href inside my db. Therefore, I need to get specific part of current page url **eg :** `abc.php`.
But now I only can get full url which is **eg :** `http://abc_system/user/abc.php`. Is it one of the solution is used `substring`?I am looking for some help. Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks in advanced.

This is my code which return url result:

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `basename()` function for get your `filename` from the URL string.

```
<?php
   $url = "http://google.com/sdfsaf/abcd.php";
   echo basename($url);  // It will returns abcd.php
?>
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/sBp8b4)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `**parse_url()**` if you want to split url to its components,
For more info, Refer : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php